# RSolve with integer and boolean variable

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, recursion, difference-equations

I have a recurrence relation with two variables $i, b$ where
$i \in \{0, \ldots, n-1\}$ for some parameter $n \in \mathbb{N}$; and $b\in \{0,1\}$.
I tried to solve it using RSolve, but the function just outputs my command (RSolve[...]) without giving any results. What am I doing wrong?

The recurrence is:

```
eqn[i_, b_] = {
f[i, b] == (1 - b) ((i r f[-1 + i, b])/(1/n + i r) + ( i r f[i, 1 - b])/(1/n + i r)) + 
                 b (f[i, 1 - b]/(1 + r/(-1 + n)) + (r f[1 + i, b])/((-1 + n) (1 + r/(-1 + n)))), 
f[0, 1] == (r f[1, 1])/(-1 + n + r), 
f[n-1, 0] == ((n-1) r)/(1 + (n-1) r) + f[n-2, 0]/( 1 + (-1 + n) r)
}
```

where $r>1$ is just some parameter.
I tried

```
RSolve[eqn[i, b], f[i, b], {i, b}]
```

Which outputs just

```
RSolve[{f[i, 
    b] == (1 - b) ((i r f[-1 + i, b])/(1/n + i r) + (
       i r f[i, 1 - b])/(1/n + i r)) + 
    b (f[i, 1 - b]/(1 + r/(-1 + n)) + (
       r f[1 + i, b])/((-1 + n) (1 + r/(-1 + n)))), 
  f[0, 1] == (r f[1, 1])/(-1 + n + r), 
  f[-1 + n, 0] == ((-1 + n) r)/(1 + (-1 + n) r) + f[-2 + n, 0]/(
    1 + (-1 + n) r)}, f[i, b], {i, b}]
```

i.e. the output is just the input we gave to mathematica.

Neither the comments here [[1]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81163/rsolve-with-two-variables) nor the proposed solution here [[2]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267611/rsolve-two-variables-with-multiple-boundary-conditions) helped me. Does anyone spot my the mistake I am making? In general, this should be a solvable recurrence.

Comment: We can also remove the boundary conditions (second and third equation: $f[0,1]$ and $f[n-1,0]$) if that helps; mathematica should then usually output free variables that one can determine manually.

Comment: Replace all `f[x,0]` with `h[x]` and all `f[y,1]` with `g[y]` in a way that captures `b={0,1}` then `{g[i]==((n-1)h[i]+r g[i+1])/(n+r-1), g[0]==r g[1]/(n+r-1),
h[i]==(i n r(h[i-1]+g[i]))/(1+i n r), h[i]==(i r+h[i-1])/(i r+1)}` and `RSolve` for `g,h`. I still don't think that is right yet.

Comment: Interesting question.  `RSolve` simply is unable to solve your problem with both boundary conditions, so it returns unevaluated.

Answer (score 1):

With the boundary conditions omitted, as permitted by @black, `RSolve` can solve this problem.

```
nobc = Replace[f[i, b] == (1 - b) ((i r f[-1 + i, b])/(1/n + i r) + 
    (i r f[i, 1 - b])/(1/n + i r)) + b (f[i, 1 - b]/(1 + r/(-1 + n)) + 
    (r f[1 + i, b])/((-1 + n) (1 + r/(-1 + n)))), {{b -> 0}, {b -> 1}}, 
    Infinity] /. {f[z_, 0] -> h[z], f[z_, 1] -> g[z]}

(* {h[i] == (i r g[i])/(1/n + i r) + (i r h[-1 + i])/(1/n + i r), 
    g[i] == (r g[1 + i])/((-1 + n) (1 + r/(-1 + n))) + h[i]/(1 + r/(-1 + n))} *)
```

where I have used @Bill's substitution, `{f[z_, 0] -> h[z], f[z_, 1] -> g[z]}` for notational simplicity.  `RSolve` immediately yields the solution

```
snobc = RSolve[nobc, {g[i], h[i]}, i] // Flatten
```

However, because this solution contains many instances of two distinct `DifferenceRoot`s, displaying it as produced by Mathematica is quite cumbersome.  Instead, do the substitution,

```
snobc /. Thread[(Cases[snobc, _DifferenceRoot, Infinity, Heads -> True] //
    Union) -> {dr1, dr2}]

(* {g[i] -> C[2] dr1[i] + C[1] dr2[i], 
    h[i] -> C[2] (dr1[i] - (r (-dr1[i] + dr1[1 + i]))/(-1 + n)) + 
        C[1] (dr2[i] - (r (-dr2[i] + dr2[1 + i]))/(-1 + n))} *)
```

where `dr1` and `dr2` represent respectively

```
{DifferenceRoot[Function[{y, m}, {-((1 + m)*n*r*(-1 + n + r)*y[m]) + 
     (-1 + n + r + 2*n*r^2 + 2*m*n*r^2)*y[1 + m] - 
     r*(1 + n*r + m*n*r)*y[2 + m] == 0, y[0] == 0, y[1] == 1}]], 
 DifferenceRoot[Function[{y, m}, {-((1 + m)*n*r*(-1 + n + r)*y[m]) + 
     (-1 + n + r + 2*n*r^2 + 2*m*n*r^2)*y[1 + m] - 
     r*(1 + n*r + m*n*r)*y[2 + m] == 0, y[0] == 1, y[1] == 0}]]}
```

The two boundary conditions can then be used to determine the constants `C[1]` and `C[2]`, at least in principle.

**Addendum: `C[1]` and `C[2]` computation**

The `i = 0` boundary condition can be applied without difficulty.

```
f[0, 1] == (r f[1, 1])/(-1 + n + r) /. f[z_, 1] -> g[z]
% /. g -> Function[i, C[2] (dr1[i] + (r dr2[i])/(-1 + n + r))] /. 
   Equal -> Rule;
snobc1 = Simplify[snobc /. %]

(* g[0] == (r g[1])/(-1 + n + r) *)
(* C[1] -> (r C[2])/(-1 + n + r) *)
(* {g[i] -> C[2] (dr1[i] + (r dr2[i])/(-1 + n + r)), 
    h[i] -> C[2] (dr1[i] + (r (dr1[i] - dr1[1 + i]))/(-1 + n) + 
    (r ((-1 + n + r) dr2[i] - r dr2[1 + i]))/((-1 + n) (-1 + n + r)))} *)
```

Note that I continue to use `dr1` and `dr2` to represent the two `DifferenceRoot`s, which would replace `dr1` and `dr2` in the actual computations.

Determining `C[2]` is much more cumbersome.

```
f[n - 1, 0] == ((n - 1) r)/(1 + (n - 1) r) + 
    f[n - 2, 0]/(1 + (-1 + n) r) /. f[z_, 0] -> h[z]
% /. h -> Function[i, C[2] (dr1[i] + (r (dr1[i] - dr1[1 + i]))/(-1 + n) + 
         (r ((-1 + n + r) dr2[i] - r dr2[1 + i]))/((-1 + n) (-1 + n + r)))];
Simplify[Solve[%, C[2]][[1, 1]]]
snobc2 = Simplify[snobc1 /. %]

(* h[-1 + n] == ((-1 + n) r)/(1 + (-1 + n) r) + h[-2 + n]/(1 + (-1 + n) r) *)
(* C[2] -> ((-1 + n) r)/((1 + (-1 + n) r) (dr1[-1 + n] + (r (dr1[-1 + n] - 
   dr1[n]))/(-1 + n) - (dr1[-2 + n] + (r (dr1[-2 + n] - 
   dr1[-1 + n]))/(-1 + n) + (r ((-1 + n + r) dr2[-2 + n] - 
   r dr2[-1 + n]))/((-1 + n) (-1 + n + r)))/(1 + (-1 + n) r) + 
   (r ((-1 + n + r) dr2[-1 + n] - r dr2[n]))/((-1 + n) (-1 + n + r)))) *)
(* {g[i] -> ((-1 + n) r (dr1[i] + 
   (r dr2[i])/(-1 + n + r)))/((1 + (-1 + n) r) (dr1[-1 + n] + 
   (r (dr1[-1 + n] - dr1[n]))/(-1 + n) - (dr1[-2 + n] + 
   (r (dr1[-2 + n] - dr1[-1 + n]))/(-1 + n) + 
   (r ((-1 + n + r) dr2[-2 + n] - 
   r dr2[-1 + n]))/((-1 + n) (-1 + n + r)))/(1 + (-1 + n) r) + 
   (r ((-1 + n + r) dr2[-1 + n] - r dr2[n]))/((-1 + n) (-1 + n + r)))), 
    h[i] -> ((-1 + n) r (dr1[i] + (r (dr1[i] - dr1[1 + i]))/(-1 + n) + 
   (r ((-1 + n + r) dr2[i] - r dr2[1 + i]))/
   ((-1 + n) (-1 + n + r))))/((1 + (-1 + n) r) (dr1[-1 + n] + 
   (r (dr1[-1 + n] - dr1[n]))/(-1 + n) - (dr1[-2 + n] + 
   (r (dr1[-2 + n] - dr1[-1 + n]))/(-1 + n) + 
   (r ((-1 + n + r) dr2[-2 + n] - r dr2[-1 + n]))/
   ((-1 + n) (-1 + n + r)))/(1 + (-1 + n) r) + 
   (r ((-1 + n + r) dr2[-1 + n] - r dr2[n]))/((-1 + n) (-1 + n + r))))} *)
```

Here is a numerical result for specific parameters.

```
Table[Simplify[snobc2 /. {n -> 5, r -> 2} /. i -> ii], {ii, 0, 4}]

(* {{g[0] -> -(391468/3850125), h[0] -> 0}, 
    {g[1] -> -(391468/1283375), h[1] -> -(71176/256675)}, 
    {g[2] -> -(462644/1283375), h[2] -> -(467728/770025)}, 
    {g[3] -> 513484/3850125, h[3] -> -(117752/256675)}, 
    {g[4] -> 1691004/1283375, h[4] -> 215072/256675}} *)
```